# OpsCenter creating cluster error

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, opscenter, nosql

I'm trying to create a new cluster in the opscenter of datastax but I already have an error that I don't understand.

In OpsCenter which address is : `localhost:8888/opscenter/index.html`

I want create a new cluster so I put the following parameters :

- Name : Test_Cluster
- Package : DataStax Community 2.0.9
- Nodes : localhost
- Node Credentials (sudo) : florian and *********************

Then, when I press the "Build Cluster" button, I get this error :

```
Install Errored : Failure installing agent on localhost.
Error output : scp. /tmp/tmpLl4kMa : Permission denied
```

Did you have an idea about my problem ?

Comment: please check this discussion - http://serverfault.com/questions/619120/setting-up-opscenter-gives-scp-tmp-permission-denied

Comment: Thanks i read it, and the problem is that there is no folder tmpLl4kMa  for me in tmp

Comment: It might have been deleted by OpsCenter after provisioning failure. Have you checked if /tmp is mounted with exec?

Comment: Does the user `florian` has [passwordless-sudo](http://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux) privileges to all the nodes in the cluster ?